# D7 views list of nodes with node reference count

Tags: views, nodes

I have two content types **A** and **B**. The content type **B** has a node reference to **A**.
I would like to create a views list which show nodes of **A** with no. of node count of **B**.
It is very similar to a list of nodes which comment count for each.

Answer (score 2):

I am not too up on D7, but the [Nodereference Count](http://drupal.org/project/nodereference_count) module has worked for me in D6 and there appears to be a D7 version.

Comment: I installed the module. But I could not see the field in my field list, except Content: Comment count and File Usage: Use count.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar 2 weeks ago. Basically you need to use a setting called **Use aggregation**, which can be found in the Views **Advanced** tab. By enabling it, you will have extra "Aggregation settings" for each field, where you can choose between (COUNT, COUNT DISTINCT, SUM, AVERAGE, etc.). A possible workflow would be:

1. Enable aggregation (Views Advanced tab --> Use aggregation).
2. Use a relationship (in your case the node reference field).
3. Add `Content: Nid` field and make it use the relationship.
4. Change the Aggregation Settings for the `Content: Nid` field to **COUNT**

That should be all!

Comment: please see this question : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20277/views-fields-and-relationship-with-aggregation