# Views Fields and Relationship with Aggregation

Tags: views, css-js-aggregation

I have three content types :
Content type A (= leg)
Content type B (= transport)
Content type C (= ticket)

B has a node reference to A.
C has a node reference to B.

I have a views list with the following and aggregation setting is on;

> > **FIELDS**
> >     Content: Nid
> >     Content: From
> >     Content: To
> >     (field_transport) MIN(Content: Price) (for)
> >     (term from field_transport_type) Taxonomy term: Name (by)
> >
> > **FILTER CRITERIA**
> >     Content: Published (Yes)
> >     Content: Type (= Leg)
> >     Content: From (exposed)
> >     Content: To (exposed)
> >
> > **SORT CRITERIA**
> >     Content: Post date (desc)
> >
> > **RELATIONSHIP**
> >     (field_transport) Content: Leg (field_leg) - reverse
> >     (field_leg) Content: Transport (field_transport) - reverse
> >     (field_leg) Content: Transport Type
> >     (term from field_transport_type) Taxonomy term: Content using Transport Type

The result with 3 records is shown as below :

> > **RESULT**
> >     How to go from Bangkok to Singapore:
> >     for $150.00
> >     by Plane
> >
> > How to go from Bangkok to Singapore:
> >     for $200.00
> >     by Train
> >
> > How to go from Bangkok to Singapore:
> >     for $80.00
> >     by Bus

I want the result with the only last line ( for $80.00 by Bus ). The result is correct before I have no relationship with `term from field_transport_type`.
How can I do that with aggregation setting `MIN` which I already applied in the field list?
I'm using drupal 7.10.

**[Edit]**
Here is the screen cast of my view :

[image]
Another thing is that the content type **B** (=transport) has a taxonomy term field (=transport type) which needs to be displayed in the field list. You can see them in the result - by Bus, by Plane, etc.

To be more clear, I attached another screen cast of my results :
[image]
The result should be 2 records above. The last three lines is the group of a leg ( Bangkok to Singpore ). This cannot be done by changing the pager settings. Pager is 10 for the page, meaning - latest 10 legs with cheapest tickets.

**[Edit]**
When I changed `field_transport_type` in FIELDS into `COUNT(DISTINCT Taxonomy term: Name)`,
I got the result with the first two lines, but I lost the transport type names.

> > How to go from New York to London: for $120.00 by 1
> >     How to go from Bangkok to Singapore: for $80.00 by 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous answer using MIN aggregation did not give me a correct result.
So, I had to write a query with subquery by myself. This query took me a few minutes to write and it gave me a exact result what I want.
I tried to create this with views for a week, but failed. What I can done with views is inner query only. May be I was missing something.

```
$result = db_query("SELECT leg.*, ( SELECT COUNT(*) from field_data_field_leg WHERE field_leg_nid = leg.nid AND bundle = :bundle ) AS reviews  FROM (
                SELECT n.nid, n.created, title, 
                    field_from_value origin, 
                    field_to_value destination, 
                    field_price_value price, 
                    term.name transport
                FROM node n 
                JOIN field_data_field_leg l ON n.nid = l.field_leg_nid
                JOIN field_data_field_from ff ON n.nid = ff.entity_id
                JOIN field_data_field_to ft ON n.nid = ft.entity_id
                JOIN field_data_field_transport t ON l.entity_id = t.field_transport_nid
                JOIN field_data_field_price p ON t.entity_id = p.entity_id
                JOIN field_data_field_transport_type ttype ON t.field_transport_nid = ttype.entity_id
                JOIN taxonomy_term_data term ON ttype.field_transport_type_tid = term.tid
                WHERE n.type = :type
                ORDER BY n.created DESC, field_price_value ASC
            ) AS leg GROUP BY nid 
            ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 10", array(':bundle'=>'review', ':type' => 'leg'));
```

By doing like this, I had to create a page with a template from a sketch with all features which drupal views provides, such as exposed filter, etc.
I think it is not a good idea, but I had to do as I have no time enough.
If you have any better idea, you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to remove the post date sort criteria, and add an ascending sort criteria for content: price. If you only want one result value, change that in the Pager area.

Comment: The result shows three tickets of 3 transport types of a leg. This is just an example for a leg. There will be many legs in the result. The target is to group transport tickets of each leg ( three records in the result ), but min-price transport ticket of each leg must be at the top. Thus, I cannot change the pager setting.

Comment: From MySQL perspective, it can be done with sub-query, but I don't know how to do with durpal views.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, when I changed the last field in field list with aggregation MIN, I achieved the result.

> > (term from field_transfport_type) MIN(Taxonomy term: Name) (by)