# Views fields relationship and node reference count

Tags: views, nodes

I have two content types A (=leg) and B(=review). The later has a node reference(=field_leg) to A.
I'm building a view. I want to include a field which displays node count of review of each leg. There are other relationships in the views, and thus, I failed to achieve it.
You can see a related question of mine [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20277/views-fields-and-relationship-with-aggregation).

[image]
Views result with the red ones are what I'm looking for.
[image]